# How to find the version of Ubuntu before booting it?

Tags: live-usb

I'm running Ubuntu OS. I have 3 flash drives (*aka USB's*) and I make all the three  USB's as bootable through unetbootin with,

- 1st USB contains **Ubuntu 14.04 desktop version-amd64**
- 2nd contains **Ubuntu 13.10 server version-amd64**
- 3rd contains **Ubuntu 12.10 desktop version-i386**

And I failed to mark the versions on the USB drives for my identification. Now I have to boot from each USB drive to know the version of Ubuntu exists in that.

Is there any way to find the version, codename, architecture of Ubuntu OS exists in that drives without booting it?

Comment: post the reason for downvote.

Comment: 2023, i still want to the know the answer to this question, the default answer doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can find the version,codename,architecture of Ubuntu OS exists in that USB drives without booting it.

#### GUI Way

Insert your flash drive and open `README.diskdefines` file present in that partition by double-clicking. First line on the file shows the version,codename,architecture of Ubuntu present inside the flash drive.

#### Command Line

```
awk -F"DISKNAME " '{ print $2; exit}' /mountpoint/README.diskdefines
```

`/mountpoit` - represents the directory where your USB drive is mounted.

*Example:*

```
 $ awk -F"DISKNAME " '{ print $2; exit}' /media/avinash/478E-0362/README.diskdefines
 Ubuntu 12.10 "Quantal Quetzal" - Release i386
```

My USB drive is mounted inside `/media/avinash/478E-0362` directory.